# Remove Right-to-left character \u200f in Python (Hebrew)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unique, right-to-left

I have a dataframe, and I want the unique strings of a specific column. The strings are in Hebrew.

Because I'm using pandas dataframe, I wrote: `all_names = history.name.unique()` (`history` is the data frame with a `name` column).

I get strange duplicates with the `\u200f` character. Like `ערן` and another one with the  `\u200f`

```
all_names
array(['\u200fערן', 'ערן',  ...., None], dtype=object)
```

How can I remove these characters? (From the original data frame)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear-up your `name` strings by filtering out all non-letters and non-whitespaces (Unicode-wise) by [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)ing a [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)-based function to all the values in the `name` column.

For example (assuming Python 3, which handles Unicode properly):

```
>>> import re
>>> history.name.apply(lambda s: s and re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', s))
```

The [`\w` includes all Unicode word characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (including numbers) and `\s` includes all Unicode whitespace characters.

By the way, the `\u200f` (aka the `RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK`) that's bothering you is in the Unicode codepoint category "Other, Format":

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name('\u200f')
'RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK'
>>> unicodedata.category('\u200f')
'Cf'
```

so, you can be sure it'll be removed with the filter above.